# Windows 7 unattended install

Tags: windows-7, answer-file

I've created a simple answer file for an unattended install, but when booting from USB, it still asks me what language, and requires that I click the 'Install Now' button before it starts. Everything else is automated. How do I automate this first part? Here's my answer file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SetupUILanguage>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        </SetupUILanguage>
        <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DiskConfiguration>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            <Disk wcm:action="add">
                <ModifyPartitions>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Active>true</Active>
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        <Label>Windows</Label>
                        <Letter>C</Letter>
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                </ModifyPartitions>
                <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                <CreatePartitions>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Extend>true</Extend>
                        <Type>Primary</Type>
                        <Order>1</Order>
                    </CreatePartition>
                </CreatePartitions>
            </Disk>
        </DiskConfiguration>
        <ImageInstall>
            <OSImage>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                <InstallToAvailablePartition>true</InstallToAvailablePartition>
            </OSImage>
        </ImageInstall>
        <UserData>
            <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
        </UserData>
    </component>
</settings>
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OOBE>
            <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
            <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
            <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
        </OOBE>
        <RegisteredOrganization>Company</RegisteredOrganization>
        <RegisteredOwner>IT Dept</RegisteredOwner>
        <TimeZone>Pacific Standard Time</TimeZone>
        <UserAccounts>
            <AdministratorPassword>
                <Value>omitted</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </AdministratorPassword>
        </UserAccounts>
    </component>
</settings>
<settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Identification>
            <Credentials>
                <Domain>domain</Domain>
                <Password>domainpass</Password>
                <Username>domainadmin</Username>
            </Credentials>
            <JoinDomain>domain</JoinDomain>
            <MachineObjectOU>OU=New,OU=ComputersOU,DC=domain,DC=com</MachineObjectOU>
        </Identification>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ProductKey>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</ProductKey>
    </component>
</settings>
<settings pass="offlineServicing">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OEMInformation>
            <Manufacturer>Company</Manufacturer>
            <SupportPhone>(XXX) XXX-XXXX</SupportPhone>
            <SupportURL>http://servicedesk/</SupportURL>
        </OEMInformation>
    </component>
</settings>
<cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim://markf/gimage/inprogressimage/install.wim#Windows 7 PROFESSIONAL" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared against my working one I can't see there's anything particularly wrong with it, there are a few missing entries in the WinPE component such as `<AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>` and the `<ImageInstall>` section but here's a copy of ours to see for yourself (sensitive bits hashed out).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <UseConfigurationSet>true</UseConfigurationSet>
      <UserData>
        <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
        <FullName>#####</FullName>
        <Organization>#####</Organization>
      </UserData>
      <ImageInstall>
        <OSImage>
          <InstallToAvailablePartition>true</InstallToAvailablePartition>
          <InstallFrom>
            <MetaData>
              <Key>/IMAGE/Name</Key>
              <Value>windows 7 enterprise</Value>
            </MetaData>
          </InstallFrom>
        </OSImage>
      </ImageInstall>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      <SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>en-GB</UILanguage>
      </SetupUILanguage>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <RegisteredOwner>#####</RegisteredOwner>
      <RegisteredOrganization>#####</RegisteredOrganization>
      <TimeZone>GMT Standard Time</TimeZone>
      <Computername>*</Computername>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <Identification>
        <JoinDomain>#####</JoinDomain>
        <MachineObjectOU>OU=Client Software,OU=SBSComputers,OU=Computers,OU=MyBusines,DC=#####,DC=#####</MachineObjectOU>
        <Credentials>
          <Domain>#####</Domain>
          <Username>administrator</Username>
          <Password>#####</Password>
        </Credentials>
      </Identification>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <RunSynchronous>
        <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
          <Path>reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\FirstNetwork" /v Category /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f</Path>
          <Description>Setting Network Location</Description>
          <Order>1</Order>
          <WillReboot>OnRequest</WillReboot>
        </RunSynchronousCommand>
      </RunSynchronous>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <OOBE>
        <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
        <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
        <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
      </OOBE>
      <UserAccounts>
        <LocalAccounts>
          <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
            <Name>#####</Name>
            <Group>Administrators</Group>
            <Password>
              <Value>#####</Value>
              <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </Password>
          </LocalAccount>
        </LocalAccounts>
      </UserAccounts>
      <ProductKey>#####</ProductKey>
    </component>
    <component xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <InputLocale>en-GB</InputLocale>
      <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
      <UILanguage>en-GB</UILanguage>
      <UILanguageFallback>en-GB</UILanguageFallback>
      <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
```

Did you use the WAIK to build this, and did it pass validation?